# Rewriting integral/summation as weighting estimator

Tags: probability, biostatistics, estimators, integral, weighted-regression

I recently read a biostats paper which featured the following identity:

$$
\sum_{y, l, m} y P(y, l, m \mid c, a) \frac{P(l \mid a, c) P\left(m \mid a^{*}, c\right)}{P(l, m \mid c, a)}=E\left(Y \frac{P\left(M \mid c, a^{*}\right)}{P(M \mid l, c, a)} \mid c, a\right)
$$

I'm struggling to figure out why the summation can be expressed in this way. I understand that $
\sum_{y, l, m} y P(y, l, m \mid c, a) = E[Y|a,c]$, and intuitively, I guess that since we're marginalizing over conditional PMFs, all the PMFs move into the expectation. However, (i) why is it that $P(y,l,m \mid c,a)$ determines the conditioning set of the final expectation. (ii) What does $P(M|c,a^*)$ actually mean (i.e. what does it mean to take the probability of random variable $M$). If you were to implement this weighting estimator, would you not want to fit a model for $Y|a,c$, where the weights for each unit are $\frac{P(M=m|C,a^*}{P(M=m|C,L,a^*}$ (i.e. $L$ and $C$ are random and take the value for each unit in the dataset, which doesn't seem to be implied by the setup here). Thanks!

**EDIT**
The equation can be found on page 26 in the supplementary material of Vanderweele et al (2014), Effect Decomposition in the Presence of an  Exposure-Induced Mediator-Outcome Confounder: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4214081/bin/NIHMS637397-supplement-Supplemental_Digital_Content.pdf

Comment: Do you mind editing the question to link to the paper? It'll help to see the original formulas and context.